# How to get location claim when using Facebook OAuth provider

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the location (or locality) for the user when using facebook OAuth (I haven't tried with google but it's something that I would like too)

I already have set up my scope in my startup file like this:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = "",
                Scope = {"email",
                        "user_friends",
                        "user_location" }
            });
```

the problem is when I do a

```
_signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()
```

I'm always getting the same claim types, so I'd like to add the locality or any other claim type available (like username instead email for example).

when I do:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    ProviderKey = info.ProviderKey,
    Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
    Name = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName),
    Surname = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Surname),
    AuthenticationType = info.LoginProvider,
    NormalizedUserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
    UserName =  info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
    Location = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Locality), // I'm getting null here
    Created = DateTime.UtcNow
 };
```

I think I need to add a configuration for those extra claims I want to collect but I'm not sure where to start, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `location` field:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
{
      AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
      AutomaticChallenge = true,
      ClientId = "",
      ClientSecret = "",
      Scope = {"email", "user_friends", "user_location" },
      Fields = {"location"}
});
```

Comment: well it worked like a charm, how do you know the fieldname is location and not user_location?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_location